# Use of 'less' with countable nouns

Tags: determiners, countable-nouns

Supposing that, a player is supposed to spend 60 minutes in a training session. He spends 57 minutes. We say:

> You have spent **less** minutes.

Is it right? I feel it is not, since 'less' modifies 'an uncountable noun'. But if we say:

> You have spent **fewer** minutes.

It gives an impression that:

*The player hasn't stayed long for the training session. Such as he spent only 5 to 10 minutes.*

Question is, how to describe this thing (that the player has spent less time than he was supposed to) using the word '**minutes**' a countable noun?

Comment: Although it should be *fewer*, neither sentence sounds normal. And the phrasing of the "impression" would be *the player hasn't stayed long **enough**  …*

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what you have said regarding less and fewer. It should be:

- You have spent less **time**. *Less + uncountable noun.*
- You have spent fewer **minutes**. *Fewer + countable noun.*

However, as a native English speaker, I wouldn't use the noun 'minutes' in this sentence personally. I would say "you haven't spent enough time training yet" or "you've spent less time training than you were supposed to". To me, "you've spent fewer minutes" sounds really formal / literal, when the message we are trying to convey is that simply not enough time has been spent training.

Comment: So if we want to use the word 'minutes' what should be the sentence?

Comment: In the case of 57 minutes out of 1 hour, you could say "You're 3 minutes short of your training period (an hour)", "You've still got 3 minutes to go", "You have spent 3 minutes fewer than you should have done".

Comment: So we can say: You made three fewer minutes. But we can't say: You made tree less minutes. Right?

Comment: Actually I want to describe the word 'minutes' with an adjective, in Present simple tens.

Comment: "You are 3 minutes short of your training period"

Comment: So, we don't have an adjective to describe this, like we have two adjectives , early and late... we say, 'These are  early minutes.' 'Those late minutes were the cause.' we can't say: fewer+minutes/hours+ be...